# MySQL Fulltext Search for attributes

Tags: mysql, sql

I am a bit new to MySQL Full Text Search capability.

I would like to clarify some usage of MATCH()..AGAINST() FTS functionality.

If we have a column of type text and which contains multiple name pair values along with other text. Generally I understand that the FTS feature in MySQL can be used as via below command:

```
select col from mytable where match(text_data) against('some word') limit 10;
```

But I need to search for multiple words like, if:

```
select text_data from mytable;
==============================

abcd, xyax&iopp data=1244 amt=78 ..
abcd, xyax&iopp data=12xx amt=7x ..
```

Now I want to search in text_data column having value data value as '1244' and amt as '78'. So how can I use two expression is AGAINST clause:

```
select col from mytable where match(text_data) against ('data=1244' and  'amt=78')

OR

select col from mytable where match(text_data) against ('data=1244') and match(text_data) against ('amt=78')
```

OR

```
select col from mytable where match(text_data) against ('data 1244 amt 78')
```

OR

is there any other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT  col
FROM    mytable
WHERE   MATCH(text_data) AGAINST('+"data 1244" +"amt 78"' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

Note that you should have `ft_min_word_len` set to 1 for this to work (with default value of 4, `amt` and `78` won't even get indexed)